# How to give RDS instance permission to invoke lambda from CFT or SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-sam

Below is what I wrote in my SAM template to give RDS permission to invoke the lambda function. I added policies key to give permission similar to other services but that does not seem to be the case with RDS.

```
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      Engine: postgres
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      DBInstanceIdentifier: testdb
      DBSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DBSecurityGroup
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Sid: LambdaCrudPolicy
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
              Resource: !GetAtt TestFunction.Arn
```

Getting error :
Properties validation failed for resource
DBInstance with message: #: extraneous key
[Policies] is not permitted

How can I give my instance lambda permission?

---

Tried AssociatedRoles, getting error - Tried, but failed with error - Resource handler returned message: "Invalid Role
ARN: event-driven-service-RootRole-4PBV76O7
(Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
46bye4ae-ca93-4a17-b47b-6c397b862c81)"
(RequestToken:
70cxa135-8d79-838c-3b31-0b146ae75db1,
HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)                                                                 The following resource(s) failed to create

Here is new cft:

```
Description: The service contains the lambda function that handles the routing of emails.
Resources: 
  RootRole: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Service: 
                - "rds.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: RDSLambdaCrud
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Sid: LambdaCrudPolicy
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Resource: "*"
  DBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: dbname
      Engine: postgres
      MasterUsername: dbuser
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
      DBInstanceIdentifier: artifacts
      AllocatedStorage: 5
      MasterUserPassword: qwert1234
      AssociatedRoles:
        - FeatureName: InvokeLambda
          RoleArn: !Ref RootRole
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [VPCSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups), not `DBSecurityGroups`. `DBSecurityGroups` exists only for backwards compatibility, and these days its not used for new RDS instances.

There is no property `Policies` in [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html). Please refer to the AWS docs linked on the valid properties that can be used with `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`.

Comment: Sure, I'll look into it, although the question is not related to that, can you please help me with the policies part?

Comment: I understood from the error that there is nothing like policies, but I am not able to figure out how to attach policies to RDS instance from cft then?

Comment: @RupaliMishra There are no such think as attaching policies to RDS instance. Its not clear what you want to accomplish. Please check AWS docs how to work with RDS instances.

Comment: I want to invoke lambda function from RDS instance but I am getting permission error, to overcome that I need to give my RDS instance permission to invoke lambda, and I am not sure how can I do that in CFT

Comment: @RupaliMishra Yes, you can attach IAM roles using `AssociatedRoles`.

Comment: Tried using AssociatedRoles, and added cft and error in the question above, can you take a look?